# my vertical x axis labels run into my plotted data. Is there a way to compress the graph so I have a little extra room at the bottom

Tags: core-plot

I am plotting my x axis labels vertically, and using the following line to provide a little space under the axis

```
axisSet.xAxis.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:40.0];
```

But now the vertical length of the label bumps into the first value on the y axis. Is there a way to compress the graph a little so the first value on the y axis begins a little higher? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the axis' `labelAlignment` and/or `labelOffset` to reposition the labels.

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way to make the actual graph area a little bit smaller so the vertical x label does not interfere with the actual graph.  I see how to adjust the offset but that just moves the label up and down. I actually need a little more real estate directly below the body of the graph because my vertical x labels are about 10 characters long and I can't figure out how to do this. Thanks.

Comment: Use the padding on the plot area and/or plot area frame to adjust the spacing between the edge of the graph and the plot area (the part where plots are drawn).